# application of inverse function theorem (first I thought implicit function theorem and then corrected it), how to continue?

Tags: derivatives

Let $f=(f_1,f_2,f_3):\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ continuously differentiable, $\det\begin{pmatrix} D_1f_1 & D_2f_1 \\ D_1f_2 & D_2f_2 \end{pmatrix}\not=0$.

How to prove: In every point $(a_1,a_2)$ exists a neigbourhood $W$ of $(a_1,a_2,0)$ and $V$ of $(f_1(a_1,a_2),f_2(a_1,a_2),f_3(a_1,a_2))$, such that there is a diffeomorphism $g:V\to W$ such that $(g\circ f)(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,x_2,0)$.

It looks like inverse function theorem, but I don't know how to apply it in detail. Could you help me? Regards

**Edit** With mathcounterexample help, (I first thought that implicit function theorem is necessary, but it's the inverse function theorem as he said), for avery $(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ exists an open neigbourhood $U_{(x_1,x_2)}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ and an an open neigbourhood $W_{f_1(x_1,x_2),f_2(x_1,x_2)}$ such that $F:U_{(x_1,x_2)}\to W_{f_1(x_1,x_2),f_2(x_1,x_2)}$ is bijective and it's inverse function is a diffeomorphism. But how I don't know, how to continue.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Apply the inverse function theorem to the function $$F : (x_1,x_2) \to (f_1(x_1,x_2),f_2(x_1,x_2))$$

Comment: thank you! I edited my answer and tried to aplly the theorem. But I don't know how to continue.